# Combining two queries in Yahoo YQL

Tags: yql, yahoo-maps

I want to get the weather information for a specific location.

Right now, I need to calls to get them: The first one translated my current position (lat/lon) to a WOEID, the second call retrieves the Weather information by using that WOEID.

Can I combine those 2 queries?

The first one is: 
    select * from yahoo.maps.findLocation where q="LAT, LON" and gflags="R"

The second one is: 
    select * from weather.bylocation where location= WOEID AND unit = 'c'

Comment: See also **[How do I combine multiple rest queries using YQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917144/how-do-i-combine-multiple-rest-queries-using-yql)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [sub-selects](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/joins.html) to join data between different queries.

In your case, you can grab the woeid from the `yahoo.maps.findLocation` table and insert that into a query against the `weather.bylocation` table as follows:

```
select * 
from weather.bylocation 
where unit = 'c' and location in (
    select Results.woeid 
    from yahoo.maps.findLocation
    where q="LAT, LON" and gflags="R"
    limit 1
)
```